# Underlying object Type of an empty Array

Tags: c#, reflection

Hej,

assuming I have a code that looks like this:

```
List<User> userList = GetUserByName (u => u.Name == name);
DoSomethingWithTheUsers (userList.ToArray ());
```

Now I want to know the type of the objects in the Array in the method *DoSomethingWithTheUsers (object[] myObjects)*

Simply done by *myObjects.First ().GetType ()* but what is to be done if the array is empty?
Is there a possibility to still get the Type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The array type will be an array of User, i.e. User[]. Why not just use Type.GetElementType() on the GetType() of the array? I.e. using your example:

```
myObjects.GetType().GetElementType()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I would expect but I what I want is: 
*User*
I need to save the FullName of the type for later, and I wondered if there is a better way, then removing the *[]* by string replace (or something like that)